# Reverse String slicing with first letter as it is

Tags: string, python-3.x

I am bit confused about reverse string slicing. I mean we have string stored in c variable , so writing it in reverse order is like c[::-1] will reverse the string. But i want to know how do i do it if i want first letter of entered string to be as it is.

Answer (score 1):

```
a[start:end:step] # start through not past end, by step

a[:1] # take first character
a[-1:0:-1] # start from end and take until first character in reverse

a[:1] + a[-1:0:-1] # what you want
```